# Why doesnt use C programming language for web development

Tags: php, c, web

i am asking myself, a lot of the web development programming language created in c/c++.
so, why people dont use C for web development in compare to web development programming languge just like PHP, C is more than fast.

Comment: And assembler is even faster.

Comment: Yes it does, but is diffcult to code in assembly.

Comment: start a new mainstream - write web applications in C and we'll catch up

Comment: Why is the voted down? It is a genuine question albeit from an inexperienced user. Someone new to web apps perhaps.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: I guess because it doesn't fit well with the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Also @NoufalIbrahim when I first read this question, it felt like a sudden thought of someone who don't have nothing else to do and is just got up after his afternoon nap..I didn't vote it down since it was already down by -4. Also "i am asking myself" is not the most promising start for a question too..

Comment: Besides, it's highly argumentative (but I didn't vote).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't C or C++ used as a web programming language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381051/why-isnt-c-or-c-used-as-a-web-programming-language)

Answer (score 4):

The kind of speed necessary for programs on the web is different from the speed needed for embedded and other high performance apps. There's a cost to developing in C. It's time consuming, error prone and very low level. If can sacrifice some of that to write code at a higher level, faster which still gets your job done, you should.

Answer (score 1):

Web development is string manipulation, and that is one of C's weaker points. Hence the popularity of languages featuring easier ways to manipulate strings, such as Perl and PHP.

Comment: -1. Web development is not "string manipulation".

Comment: my -1 is for this reason as well

Comment: +1. Similarly, it's not all that much fun trying to do anything like an ORM in C.

Comment: That is true but the statement "web development is string manipulation" is still *way* off the mark. Your point about ORMs is not particularly relevant here.

Comment: So when was the last time you were using a data structure more sophisticated than an array in web development. A min-heap? A BST of hashes over strings? Also, one seldom sees an implementation of Edmonds-Karp in PHP. Or a decent sweepline algorithm. Unless proven wrong, I still argue that in web development, the hard part is manipulating strings, possibly storing them in a database.

Comment: The request headers are received as a string. The response is sent out as a string. JSON is used commonly - and it's a string representation of arbitrary data. Web develoment is precisely about being able to produce a string out of another string. It's just abstracted away, so perhaps not apparent.

Comment: That's just I/O isn't it? Receive strings and output strings. However, if you think that people don't use C for web programming just because its string manipulation abilities are weak, I don't think a discussion will be fruitful.

Comment: 3 downvotes, 3 upvotes. So far.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: why? Do you think anything but input and producing an output matters? While I agree this is definitely not the reason behind not using C for web development (TIME is the reason, or more precisely, MONEY that is charged for development time), producing a website has only two required elements: input and output :).

Comment: The point is the code that goes into "converting" the input to output.  Massaging textual input to an internal format and then back is a thin part of web apps and that part is mostly just string manipulation. The meat of the app is in between and that could be as simple or as complicated as any other. This is just like saying photoshop is "pixel manipulation" or a some control system software is "servo manipulation". And the selection of something other than C has nothing to with this (as you've rightly noted).

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim And the meat of the app is in 99% of the cases just string manipulation as well (CRUD isn't exactly rocket science). Just because there is a chance for it not just being string manipulation doesn't mean you can't make this generalised statement about web development.